# No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts! in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I created a simple application for testing, I am getting - "No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!" error, i have checked different posts related to the same but of no help.

My Structure is  App Module has App Routing Module and from which i am doing lazy loading to Routing example module (which again has routing module).

App Routing Module

```
const parentRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: () =>
    import('./routing-example/routingexample.module').then(
      (x) => x.RoutingExampleModule
    ),
  },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(parentRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

App Module File

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Routing Example Routing Module

```
import { Component1 } from "./component1/component1.component";
import { Component2 } from "./component2/component2.component";
import { RoutingExampleComponent } from "./routingexample.component";


export const compRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RoutingExampleComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'comp1',
        component: Component1,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'comp2',
        component: Component2,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'comp1',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(compRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class RoutingExampleRoutingModule {

}
```

Routing example Module -

```
import { RoutingExampleComponent } from "./routingexample.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RoutingExampleRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RoutingExampleComponent,
   Component1,
   Component2
  ],
})
export class RoutingExampleModule {
 
}
```

My Application html has only -

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I know because of this only issue coming but dont know the exact issue though,

Any help  would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it's better to create stackblitz link, could you update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved.

I have added the same things in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2gnjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts),

It is working there !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form in your html, then you have to import ReactiveFormsModule in RoutingExampleModule, however I am not sure this will solve your problem.

Try import ReactiveFormsModule, sometimes this may create this type of issues.

Comment: No I am not using the form controls.